# Expectation of an integral with a random variable on its borne

Tags: probability, statistics

Having a random variable $T$ with a known distribution:

1. Is it correct to say that $E\left[\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}a\,dt\right]=a\times E[T]$ ?
2. How can we calculate $E\left[\displaystyle \int_{0}^{T}f(t)\,dt\right]$  with $f(t)$ a known function of $t$ ?

Comment: What is the function $f(t)$?

Comment: Re 2, use that $$\int_0^Tf(t)dt=\int_0^\infty f(t)\mathbf 1_{T>t}dt$$ to deduce that $$E\left(\int_0^Tf(t)dt\right)=\int_0^\infty f(t)P(T>t)dt$$